# ERROR 1064 (42000) while running file.sql file in putty

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

my file.sql has below code

```
use Database_name;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Create_Calendar_Date()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO CALENDAR_DATE
select date_format(selected_date,'%Y%m%d') CALENDAR_DATE,
    week(SELECTED_DATE) WEEK_NUMBER,
    substr(monthname(SELECTED_DATE),1,3) MONTH_NAME,
    month(SELECTED_DATE) MONTH_NUMBER,
    year(SELECTED_DATE) YEAR_NAME,
    dayname(SELECTED_DATE) DAY_NAME,
    concat( 'Q',quarter(SELECTED_DATE)) QUARTER_LABEL,
    extract(year_month from selected_date) MONTH_SPLIT_NAME,
    concat( year(SELECTED_DATE),concat('Q',timestampdiff(month, @FiscalYearStartDate, @today) div 3 + 1)) FISCAL_QUARTER_LABEL,
    dayofyear(selected_date) DAY_OF_YEAR,
     'N' ORGANAIZATION_HOLIDAY
from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between MAKEDATE(year(DATE_ADD(date_format(sysdate(),'%Y%m%d'),interval -2 YEAR)),1) and 
        LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(date_format(sysdate(),'%Y%m%d'),interval 5 YEAR), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(DATE_ADD(date_format(sysdate(),'%Y%m%d'),interval 5 YEAR)) MONTH));           
END
```

In my putty I am calling this code like

```
mysql -u root -p <Database Name> < file.sql
```

when I execute this I am getting error like below
**ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 24**

I am new to this putty type coding.., what is the problem here??

Comment: Removed the 'putty' tag because there's no reason to think this error is related to putty.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Putty issue, this is a MySQL error. You have something incorrect in your SQL syntax. Your query is pretty complicated so you may want to simplify it, individually test your sub-queries, and validate it using an online validator https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+validator&oq=mysql+validator.

To troubleshoot you should open up an interactive SQL session in Putty and enter 1 SQL statement at a time until you locate the erroneous line. At this point you will need to troubleshoot exactly what part is incorrect SQL.

The steps will resemble this:

> Use Putty to ssh into your mysql host. Once in the host's terminal enter the commands:

```
$ mysql -u root -p <Database Name>
$ mysql> use Database_name;
$ mysql> <enter more SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using syntax like this inside my file.sql file

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_Create_Calendar_Date`;
DELIMITER //
USE `DATABASE_NAME`

CREATE PROCEDURE`sp_Create_Calendar_Date` ()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO CALENDAR_DATE
SELECT..... ; /* Query as it's like in my question */

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

In my server the SQL file was in same location where I am executing so I called my SQL file like this

```
mysql -u root -p <DATABASE_NAME> < file.sql
```

store procedure created in my database. I am aware that it's not PuTTY issue